# Is there a buck-boost converter with I2C digital control from a microcontroller?

Tags: power-supply, power, i2c, converter

I want to build a portable pocket power supply with a digital voltage/current control (controlled by Arduino).

After doing research I realized that there is no simple way to do it with simple buck/boost converters since digital potentiometers are designed for low voltage and can't be used to control DC/DC converters.

Are there buck-boost converters with I2C control? I mean ones that are popular and available to buy, ideally ready to use (soldered schematic on boards).

Comment: There are buck devices that provide digital control of the output voltage and, there are boost devices with digital voltage output control. I've not seen buck-boost with this facility. Please state the output current range and both input and output voltage range you need. There may be demo boards available too.

Comment: You can suggest any, BUCK or BOOST, maybe I will find something useful. BOOST will be preferred better to use with LIPO battery. My current DC DC is FP5139 based SEPIC converter, it work from 3.2V to 30V at input and at the output can get from 0.5V to 30V. But i cannot control it digitaly. Initially i need converted that will work from 4-8V at input and at the output i need from 0.5 (1) V to 20 (or 30) V.

Comment: You forgot to mention current.

Comment: 2-3A would be enough.

Comment: If your Arduino includes a DAC you can use that and a resistor to set the output voltage. I've used one to set a boost converter from 10-60v before. Even easier than i2c.

Answer (score 4):

Using a digital POT has drawbacks related to bandwidth (due to internal stray capacitance), and also the output voltage changing non-linearly with the POT setting.  Here is a method that gets around both of those problems.

A typical setup for many buck converters is to use a pair or resistors (R1, R2) connected to between the output voltage (VOUT) the feedback pin (VFB) and ground.  In this case the output voltage is normally

$$ V_{OUT} = V_{FB}\frac{R_1+R_2}{R2} $$

But if we connect the other end of the feedback network to a DAC instead of ground, we can achieve variable output voltage depending on the DAC setting.

$$ V_{OUT} = V_{FB}\frac{R_1+R_2}{R2} - V_{DAC}\frac{R_1}{R_2} $$

This method works for any DC-DC converter that uses a resistor feedback network.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDtijT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, there are some DC-DC converter ICs that have built in I2C (SMBUS) control.  They are made by manufacturers like Analog Devices, Texas Instruments, etc.

Comment: Please note that I have actually built and tested a circuit board using the DAC based voltage control method.  There have been several thousand copies of the board sold and there have never been any reported issues with that feature over the last several years.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an external IC with I2C control to control the voltage feedback loop of any DC DC controller that has the loop exposed. The IC creates a current source/sink that can change the voltage operating point of the voltage feedback loop. Keep in mind that changing the operating point could drive the DC DC controller into unstable regions, I overcame that problem by simulating the DC DC controller at it's highest and lowest voltage that the IC could produce. You also have to do a bit of math with the feedback resistors to change the voltage operating range.

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc7106.html

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting. The problem i see is it going to be 128 steps if 7 bit chip used?
My DC DC is FP5139 based SEPIC converter, seems like also can be regulated that way with FB input.

Comment: If you needed more steps you would have to find a different current sink, you could design one yourself but this is the one I have used in the past.

Comment: I found similar, LTC1427-50 is a 10-bit, current-output DAC with an SMBus interface:  https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/smbus-controlled-10bit-current-output-50ua-full-scale-dac.html
The problem is how to get it now. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: MCP4725 12 bit DAC is cheap and available, will try to do a test with it.
https://curiousscientist.tech/blog/mcp4725-szbk07-circuit-control

Comment: It's better to use a current source DAC, but a 10k resistor attached to a voltage source (the DAC) is a surrogate, but kind of a kludge.  If you need linearity, then use a current source DAC.

Comment: Thank you, will search for cheap one.

Answer (score 0):

The USB PD (power delivery) 3 standard allows programmable power supplies in order to support fast charging of smartphones. So search for converters designed for that, e.g., [TPS55289](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS55289)/8:

[image: TPS55289]

Comment: Thank you, honestly it looks great, add inductor and ready. The only problem is it seems like you need to buy quantity of 3000 to get it.

Comment: No; you can buy cut tape.